# How to replace internal double quotes in one field of a pipe-separated file

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have a PSV file:

```
$ cat hello.txt 
123|"xy"|11|"sb" sri"|13|"bb" 
123|"xy"|11|"rss" "NIL"|13|"bb"
```

In the 4th field, I want to replace the internal double-quotes with a different character (`W`).

Here is what I tried, which doesn't yet do what I want.

```
$ sed '/"|/s/[^|]|/W|/4' hello.txt 
123|"xy"|11|"sb" sriW|13|"bb" 
123|"xy"|11|"rss" "NILW|13|"bb"
```

I'd like the output to be like this in the `hello.txt` file below.

```
$ cat hello.txt 
123|"xy"|11|"sbW sri"|13|"bb" 
123|"xy"|11|"rssW WNIL"|13|"bb"
```

Answer (score 2):

Looking at it from a different point of view,

```
123|"xy"|11|"sb" sri"|13|"bb" 
123|"xy"|11|"rss" "NIL"|13|"bb"
```

you want to extract the fourth pipe-delimited field:

```
cut -f4 -d'|' < test

"sb" sri"
"rss" "NIL"
```

Then there might be quotes inside the field, so get rid of the outer pair

```
cut -f4 -d'|' < test | sed -e 's/^"\(.*\)"/\1/g'

sb" sri
rss" "NIL
```

replace any remaining quotes with the W sign

```
cut -f4 -d'|' < test | sed -e 's/^"\(.*\)"/\1/g' | tr '"' 'W'

sbW sri
rssW WNIL
```

and finally replace back the outer quotes

```
cut -f4 -d'|' < test | sed -e 's/^"\(.*\)"/\1/g' | tr '"' 'W' \
    | sed -e 's/\(.*\)/"\1"/g'

"sbW sri"
"rssW WNIL"
```

Answer (score 1):

It would appear that you want to replace "internal double-quotes" from the 4th field of your pipe-delimited file with `W`. This can be done using `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} {gsub(/^\"|\"$/,"",$4);gsub(/\"/,"W",$4);$4="\"" $4 "\""}1' hello.txt
```

This command will first remove opening and closing double-quotes from the 4th field, then replace the remaining ones with `W`, and re-add one opening and one closing double-quote around the text.

Result:

```
123|"xy"|11|"sbW sri"|13|"bb" 
123|"xy"|11|"rssW WNIL"|13|"bb"
```